# Passing a string variable to rename function pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to rename a single column in a DataFrame by passing in a string variable to rename function and getting the below error, any help is much appreciated.

```py
import pandas as pd

new = "new_name"

df.rename(index=str, columns={"old_name": new})
```

The error:

```
TypeError: 'set' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the index=str bit, this will work unless your column is your index:

```
new="new_name"
df.rename(columns={'old_name':new})
```

input:

```
   ID1  old_name      Date
0    1    2      1/1/2018
1    1    2      3/1/2018
2    1    2      4/5/2018
```

output:

```
   ID1    new_name      Date
0    1         2    1/1/2018
1    1         2    3/1/2018
2    1         2    4/5/2018
```

if you want to save it:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'old_name':new})
```

if you want to rename index:

```
df.index.rename(new, inplace=True)
```

output:

```
          ID1   ID2      Date
new_name                    
0           1    2    1/1/2018
1           1    2    3/1/2018
2           1    2    4/5/2018
```